# ¿Como establezco comparo fechas y envió alarmas?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

buenas, les comento: Yo tengo un registro en una base de datos con la fecha en que fue creado ese registro. Lo que quiero es que pasado cierto tiempo sin que algún campo esa TABLA en la base de datos sea modificado, me muestre una alarma. Los pongo en contexto de lo que estoy haciendo: Es una plataforma de PQRS, entonces cuando ingresen uno nuevo, el funcionario debería revisarlo y solucionarlo y llevar a cabo todo el proceso, bien, todo eso ya está, lo que falta es que si el funcionario no lo revisa por X o Y motivo, no hay una forma "visual" de darse cuenta de que ese PQR lleva tiempo sin ser revisado o sin ser solucionado... Espero que me entiendad y me ayuden por favor. He estado leyendo un poco sobre DateTime::diff pero me resulta algo confuso y creo que ahí está la solucion...

Comment: ¿a qué lugar pretendes mandar esas alertas?

Comment: Enviar una alerta plantea un desafío mucho mayor que simplemente *desplegar* una alerta cuando el funcionario se loguea. Lo primero implica programar una tarea en el cron que pueda enviar un correo, o un mensaje a una cola de mensajería como RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enviar una alarma sin intervención de terceros implica generar un cronjob que corra un programa, dentro del cual corras una query levantando los registros que no se han revisado/actualizado en los últimos N días y si el conteo tiene filas, enviar una alerta con el contenido de la query procesado para hacerlo comprensible. Esta alerta podría ser con un correo o una cola de mensajes como RabbitMQ.

Un enfoque más sencillo podría ser que, cada vez que un funcionario entre al sistema, se le presente, si corresponde, un listado con los registros que no se han actualizado.

Ambas querys son iguales, sólo difiere la implementación para avisar la situación.

Basándonos [en este fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78232b/1), supongamos que la definición de tu tabla es

```
CREATE TABLE registros (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     fecha DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Y le insertamos registros al azar con fechas dentro de los últimos 30 días (yo ejecuté lo siguiente 16 veces)

```
insert into registros values (null, NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR( RAND( ) * 30) DAY);
```

Para listar los registros que no se han actualizado en los últimos 14 días:

```
SELECT id, 
       timestampdiff(DAY,fecha,now()) dias_sin_actualizar 
FROM registros
WHERE timestampdiff(DAY,fecha,now()) > 14
```